# Color area between curves in Octave

Tags: plot, octave, fill

I'm trying to color respectively fill, the area between two curves.
Let's say I have a `sTime` array [n×1] and two data arrays `s1` and `s2` both [n×1]. `c` is basically a color array, let's say `[1 0 0]` red color.

I'm trying with:

```
fill([sTime  flipud(sTime)], [s1  flipud(s2)],c);
```

But I obtain the following result, i.e. no color appears:
[image: FILL-RESULT-IMAGE]

I've also tried to change the dimensions of the arrays (columns to rows) with the following line, but the result is still the same.

```
fill([sTime'  fliplr(sTime')], [s1'  fliplr(s2')],c);
```

Do you have any suggestions or hints to solve this problem?

Comment: have a look at the "area" function and/or create a comple minimalistic example which values for sTime, s1 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but try this example:

```
x = (1:10)'
y = rand(10,1);
fill([x; flipud(x)], [y; -flipud(y)], [1 0 0])
```

[image: Plot of output of fill() command given]